# Module not found in same directory as running script when installed as a package

Tags: python, module, package, python-packaging

I have installed a custom package I made called pytable using `python setup.py develop` in the package folder. The package hierarchy looks like this:

- pytable/

  - __pycache__/
  - MANIFEST.in
  - pytable/

    - __init__.py
    - __pycache__/
    - pytable.py (main module)
    - tableError.py (class with custom errors)
    - testScript.py (imports pytable.py)
  - README.md
  - setup.py

The tableError.py module is imported into the pytable.py module and works fine when running testScript.py without having pytable installed with python, but when I install it with the above command and run `import pytable from pytable` anywhere else it errors.

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tableError'*

Comment: What command do you use to run the script? What is the result of `python -m pytable.testScript`?

Comment: @sinoroc Yes. No -m though.

Comment: Did you try `python -m pytable.testScript`? With `-m`, dot instead of slash and no `.py`. Is the result any better?

Comment: @sinoroc there are no problems with running testScript, just anything outside of the package importing pytable.

Comment: @sinoroc Oh I understand where you’re going. Running “python -m pytable.testScript” errors with “no module named pytable.testScript.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Maybe the project is not correctly installed. Maybe edit the question to show the content of `setup.py`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was after the package was installed Python did not know where to look to find depending modules. Adding...

```
import os
import sys
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(dir_path)
```

...to the top of pytable.py tells Python to look in the same directory where it is installed for tableError.py.

Comment: This kind of things is almost never necessary. There is most likely a more straightforward and cleaner solution.

Comment: @sinoroc agreed. This does work for now though. Let me know if you find anything.

Comment: One possibility I can think of, is that maybe there is an issue with the packaging. Maybe edit your question to show the content of `setup.py`. Or look at the output of `pip show --files pytable`.